# NSPredicate 'IN' operator formatting issue in swift. Unable to parse the format string

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am getting an exception when trying to create NSPredicate object that goes like:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "addonCategoryId IN \(idsArray)")
```

where `idsArray` is made up of `Int` objects in swift array. Exception is raised at this line itself. 
Console says:

> 2015-10-08 08:21:42.878 bkApp[2569:510538] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to
>   parse the format string "addonCategoryId IN [5404, 5406]"'

What could be the issue? Thanks for taking a look. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSPredicate` is still expecting Objective-C style format string. You used string interpolation.

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "addonCategoryId IN \(idsArray)")
// result: addonCategoryId IN [5404, 5406]
```

Try this:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "addonCategoryId IN %@", idsArray)
// result: addonCategoryId IN {5404, 5406}
```

The difference is subtile `[]` vs. `{}` but if `NSPredicate` doesn't like it, it doesn't like it.

Comment: oh I did not know about this feature of swift. thanks